# Java y XML: Problema al cargar imagenes

Tags: java, xml, jsp

Al parsear un XML con netbeans, usando java y un .jsp, intento realizar una tabla donde muestre las imágenes del XML. El parseo va bien, pero cuando lo lanzo a un navegador (he usado todos lo navegadores) no cargan las imágenes (jpg).

-AQUI PARTE DEL XML:

```
<Camaras>
   <Camara>
     <Posicion>
        <Latitud>40.40376974</Latitud>
        <Longitud>-3.66657048</Longitud>
     </Posicion>    
<URL>www.mc30.es/components/com_hotspots/
 datos/imagenes_camaras/09NC39TV01.jpg</URL>
      </Camara>
       </Camaras>
```

-AQUI PARTE DEL JSP:

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es-ES">
      <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Ejemplo con 2 cabeceras</title>
      </head>
   <body>        
            <table border="2">
        <tr><td>Longitud</td><td>Latitud</td><td>Camara</td></tr>
        <%
            for (int i=0; i<lista_camaras.size(); i++)
            { 
            Camara d=lista_camaras.get(i);
            String url="http://"+d.getUrl();
            String url_minusculas=(url.toLowerCase());
        %>
        <tr>
            <td><%=d.getLatitud()%></td>
            <td><%=d.getLongitud()%></td>
            <td> <img src="<%=url_minusculas %>"/> </td>                
        </tr>
            <%}%>        
    </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

-El problema es que al lanzarlo al navegador, me carga bien los datos, pero no las imágenes:

[image: error]

-Pero al inspeccionar, la url está bien y si la copio y pego en el navegador, la imagen carga perfectamente. La consola me da este error:

**Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE**

¿Alguien ha tenido un problema parecido?

**Añado comienzo del código HTML generado:

```html
<table border="2">
 <tr><td>Longitud</td><td>Latitud</td> <td>Camara</td></tr>

   <tr>
    <td>40.40376974</td>
    <td>-3.66657048</td>
    <td> <img src="http://www.mc30.es/components/com_hotspots/datos/imagenes_camaras/09nc39tv01.jpg" />     </td>                
  </tr>

<tr>
  <td>40.40016472</td>
  <td>-3.71215353</td>
  <td> <img src="http://www.mc30.es/components/com_hotspots/datos/imagenes_camaras/15rr64tv01.jpg"/>     </td>                
</tr>
</table>
```

Un saludo

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el HTML generado? Al menos un par de filas para comprobar qué tienen los navegadores

Comment: Añadido código HTML generado

Comment: Pues sinceramente no veo qué problema tienes aparte de que esas URL me dan 404 (no se encuentran las imágenes). Si las copio a una nueva pestaña en el navegador, también me dan 404

Comment: Es lo raro, si copias la url de la imagen, la pegas en el navegador y das al Enter, te sale el error 404. Pero si pinchas en la url del navegador y vuelves a presionar Enter, la imagen se carga.  Es la primera vez que veo algo así

Comment: Usa esta URL, que es la primera imagen:  http://www.mc30.es/components/com_hotspots/datos/imagenes_camaras/09nc39tv01.jpg

Comment: A mi me da siempre 404, he probado a refrescar con F5, con Ctrl+F5.... y nada, es siempre 404

Comment: Como comentaba, la imagen no carga al refrescar, carga haciendo exactamente como decía, copias url en la barra de direcciones del navegador, presionas intro y te da el 404. Pinchas en la barra de direcciones y vuelves a dar intro y me carga....

Comment: Me carga cuando cambio el nombre del archivo a todo mayúsculas (me he puesto a mirar las cámaras de la web a ver cómo eran las URL): http://www.mc30.es/components/com_hotspots/datos/imagenes_camaras/09NC39TV01.jpg

Comment: No sé por qué haces el toLowerCase, pero es la causa de tu problema

Comment: El toLowerCase lo usé al final, ya que no sabía que podía estar pasando. Tampoco funcionaba con la URL tal cual la recperaba del XML, con mayusculas y minusculas...

Comment: en tu xml de ejemplo hay un espacio, estás seguro que debería de ser así?

Answer (score 0):

Según tu ejemplo, el problema es que la URL no debes de pasarla a minúsculas como lo haces con la llamada a `url.toLowerCase()`.

```html
<table border="2">
 <tr><td>Longitud</td><td>Latitud</td> <td>Camara</td></tr>

   <tr>
    <td>40.40376974</td>
    <td>-3.66657048</td>
    <td> <img src="http://www.mc30.es/components/com_hotspots/datos/imagenes_camaras/09NC39TV01.jpg" />     </td>                
  </tr>

<tr>
  <td>40.40016472</td>
  <td>-3.71215353</td>
  <td> <img src="http://www.mc30.es/components/com_hotspots/datos/imagenes_camaras/15RR64TV01.jpg"/>     </td>                
</tr>
</table>
```